# Resharper 4.5: How can I discard an interface and change all references to the only implementation?

Tags: c#, interface, resharper, resharper-4.5

Given:

- I have an interface.
- I have only class that implements that interface.

Question:

> With Resharper 4.5 - How can I discard that interface and change all references to the only implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this "automagically" in one step.

What I would do in this situation is the following:

1. "Safe-Delete" (Ctrl-R,D [VS] or Alt-Del [IDEA]) the interface, leaving the code with compilation errors.
2. Navigating to the next error using (Alt-Shift-PgDn [VS] or Alt-F12 [IDEA]).
3. Pressing Alt-Enter and selecting `"Change all IYourInterfaceName"` and typing the concrete class name.

Hope that helps.